# Feature edition errors

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, feature-service

I've created a feature editor, of a puntual feature layer, in a flex 3.1 client. The feature layer is served by a feature service in ArcGIS Server 10.0.
When I try to update or delete features (I didn't try creation), I get errors eventhough the changes are made in the database. 
The errors are like these :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul.
    at com.esri.ags.components::Editor/saveUnsavedAttributes()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\components\Editor.as:5189]
    at com.esri.ags.components::Editor/attributeInspector_saveFeatureHandler()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\components\Editor.as:2674]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at com.esri.ags.components::AttributeInspector/dispatchSaveFeatureEvent()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\components\AttributeInspector.as:1030]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12232]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12170]


TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul.
    at com.esri.ags.components::Editor/featureLayer_editsCompleteHandler()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\components\Editor.as:1491]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at com.esri.ags.layers::FeatureLayer/http://www.esri.com/2008/ags/internal::editHandler()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\layers\FeatureLayer.as:2638]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncResponder.as:95]
    at com.esri.ags.tasks::FeatureLayerTask/handleApplyEdits()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\tasks\FeatureLayerTask.as:311]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::call()
    at com.esri.ags.tasks::BaseTask/handleResultEvent()[C:\checkout\flex_api3\api\src\com\esri\ags\tasks\BaseTask.as:729]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncResponder.as:95]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncToken/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::applyResult()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncToken.as:239]
    at mx.rpc.events::ResultEvent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::callTokenResponders()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\events\ResultEvent.as:207]
    at HTTPOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\http\HTTPService.as:991]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:318]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:84]
    at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/completeHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:451]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()[/CODE]
```

In the code I have declared the editor inside the  along with a geometry service:

```
<esri:Editor id="mainEditor" map="{mainMap}" geometryService="{geometryService}" />
```

And I assigned the following method to 'initialize' attribute of the application:

```
 protected function application_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                mainEditor.featureLayers = [arrets];

            }
```

where "arrets" is the name of the feature layer I want to edit.

Do you have any idea of why the errors appear?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: the feature layer I was trying to edit participates in a non-versioned network dataset => not editable. In order to edit layers participating in network datasets, the dataset must be versioned.